# Question on a theorem about group extensions

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology

I am reading the chapter [Second cohomology groups](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S030402080970146X) of [Continuation of the Notas de Matemàtica](https://www.sciencedirect.com/bookseries/north-holland-mathematics-studies/vol/177/suppl/C).

Part 1 in theorem 1.2 tells us that

Let $E : 1 \to A \xrightarrow{i} X \xrightarrow{f}  G \to 1$ be an extension of $A$ by $G$. Let $t : G \to X$ be a section of $f$ i.e. $t(1) = 1$ and $f \circ t = 1_G$.
The formula $^x a = t(x)at(x)^{-1}$ determines an action of $G$ on $A$, which depends only on the equivalence class of $E$.

I am able to prove that the given formula gives an action. Now I want to prove that it only depends on the equivalence class of $E$.

If $E' : 1 \to A \xrightarrow{i} Y \xrightarrow{g}  G \to 1$ is another extension that is equivalent to $E$, then without loss of generality, we may take $X=Y$ and $f=g$.
Suppose $s$ is another section of $f$, and $ x * a $ denotes the corresponding action. I defined $\phi : A \to A$ given by $a \mapsto t(x) s(x)^{-1} a s(x) t(x)^{-1}$. It is easy to see that $\phi(x*a) = {^xa}$. Also, I verified that $\phi$ is injective and surjective as follows:
$$\phi(a) = \phi(b) \implies t(x) s(x)^{-1} a s(x) t(x)^{-1}=t(x) s(x)^{-1} b s(x) t(x)^{-1} \implies a = b.$$

Given $b \in A$ we see that $\phi(t(x)^{-1} s(x) b s^{-1}(x) t(x)) = b$.
So $\phi$ is bijective and preserves group actions.

My doubt is that I have not used the fact that $s$ and $t$ are sections. Where am I missing?

{The same question is asked on [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4604373/a-doubt-in-a-theorem-about-group-extensions).}

Comment: TeX note: $\phi(x * a) = ^xa$ `\phi(x * a) = ^xa` doesn't work as intended; you need something like $\phi(x * a) = {^xa}$ `\phi(x * a) = {^xa}`.  I have edited accordingly.  (I would also recommend against using $x$ for elements of $G$ when you also have $X$ around, but at least context makes it fairly clear.)  \\ It may be as simple as that you don't even have an action unless $s$ and $t$ are sections.  (That is, e.g., $t(x)a t(x)^{-1}$ is *a priori* only in $X$; to show that it is actually in $A$, you need to know that its image under $f$ in $G$ is trivial.)

Comment: Got it, thank you.